# Ionic - Push notifications to users in same group

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification

I just learning Ionic framework and want to know something according to push notifications.

In my app i have user-groups and i want to let the user send push-notifications to their groupmembers.

Is this possible?
Can i use Ionic-push for this or maybe push.js ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cordova plugin [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) . You have to import `Push` from `ionic-native` to use it in `ionic`. Here is a quick example.

```
import {Push} from 'ionic-native' ;

push = Push.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "12345679"
    },
    browser: {
        pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
    },
    windows: {}
});

this.push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId
});

this.push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
});

this.push.on('error', function(e) {
    // e.message
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Ill try it out and let you know if it worked!

Comment: @Webbie Happy to help. Mark as answer if it helped with your problem.